# ValueError when using python venv

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api, python-venv

I'am currently trying to connect to my dropbox account using the API key in python. When i run it not using the virtual environment, I am able to get my profile information from the code below.

```py
import dropbox

d = dropbox.Dropbox("myAPIkey")
    
print(d.users_get_current_account())
```

But when i run the code using my python venv, i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\timeout.py", line 142, in _validate_timeout
    float(value)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timeout'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "d:/Desktop/FYP/FYP-TheBoyes/dropbox_tester.py", line 8, in <module>
        print(d.users_get_current_account())
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\dropbox\base.py", line 5216, in users_get_current_account
        r = self.request(
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\dropbox\dropbox_client.py", line 321, in request
        res = self.request_json_string_with_retry(host,
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\dropbox\dropbox_client.py", line 476, in request_json_string_with_retry
        return self.request_json_string(host,
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\dropbox\dropbox_client.py", line 588, in request_json_string
        r = self._session.post(url,
      File "d:\Desktop\FYP\FYP-Django\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 522, in post
        return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
      File "d:\Desktop\FYP\FYP-Django\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "d:\Desktop\FYP\FYP-Django\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "d:\Desktop\FYP\FYP-Django\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 413, in send
        resp = conn.urlopen(
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 687, in urlopen
        timeout_obj = self._get_timeout(timeout)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 330, in _get_timeout
        return Timeout.from_float(timeout)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\timeout.py", line 179, in from_float
        return Timeout(read=timeout, connect=timeout)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\timeout.py", line 103, in __init__
        self._connect = self._validate_timeout(connect, "connect")
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\timeout.py", line 144, in _validate_timeout
        raise ValueError(
    ValueError: Timeout value connect was Timeout(connect=100, read=100, total=None), but it must be an int, float or None.
```

Any way i can get this code to run in my python venv?

Comment: `when i run the code using my python venv`: Are you sure you are using the venv? How do you execute your code?

Comment: In my vscode, after selecting the interpreter location, there is a (venv) in my terminal, `(venv) D:\Desktop\FYP>` ,and i run it from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you're using `venv` ?
If yes, then try running it without `venv`.
And keep your **API** in a seperate variable.
And try uninstalling **Dropbox** with `pip uninstall dropbox` and then install it by `pip install dropbox`.

Comment: yes it works fine without venv, but when using venv the error occurs.

Comment: Then it is surely the problem with the **Dropbox** installation. Please try creating a new `venv` and installing **Dropbox** again there.

Comment: I have tried to create a new environment, and reinstall dropbox but i still get the same error

Comment: Outside of the `venv` run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to see what modules/packages are installed and search **Dropbox** to know what version is installed. And run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in `venv` and search **Dropbox** to know what version is installed there.

Comment: Both have the same versions of dropbox

Comment: Can you give me the requirements.txt of both of them ?

Comment: outside of venv: `certifi==2017.7.27.1
chardet==3.0.4
dropbox==11.4.1
idna==2.6
ply==3.11
requests==2.25.1
six==1.15.0
stone==3.2.1
urllib3==1.26.4` , inside of venv: `certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==3.0.4
dropbox==11.4.1
idna==2.5
ply==3.11
requests==2.25.1
six==1.15.0
stone==3.2.1
urllib3==1.21.1`

Comment: I that is the complete source code of your project which you've given here ?<br>If not then please see the line **82** of your file.<br>If yes then please copy the requirements.txt outside of `venv` to `venv` directory and run `pip install -r requirements.txt` within `venv`.

Comment: I have updated the error output, my file only had those 2 lines of code but lots of comments above it, thats why it shows the error at line 82

Comment: Then please copy the `requirements.txt` from outside of `venv` to `venv` directory and run `pip install -r requirements.txt` when there is **(venv)** before prompt in terminal.

Comment: outside of venv: `certifi==2017.7.27.1 chardet==3.0.4 dropbox==11.4.1 idna==2.6 ply==3.11 requests==2.25.1 six==1.15.0 stone==3.2.1 urllib3==1.26.4` , inside of venv: `certifi==2017.7.27.1 chardet==3.0.4 dropbox==11.4.1 idna==2.5 ply==3.11 requests==2.25.1 six==1.15.0 stone==3.2.1 urllib3==1.21.1`

Comment: Please use it without `venv` and your work will be completed.

Comment: i need to use it in venv because im going to use it in my django web app

Comment: According to the **DropBox** Team the error is due to both `requests` and `urllib3` version compatibility issues. Try `pip install requests==2.17.1 urllib3==1.26.4` within `venv`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230348/discussion-between-rajdeep-and-master-irfan-elahee).

Comment: Please accept the Question Edit. And has my last answer solve your question ?

Comment: yup, redownloaded according to the versions you stated, and it has worked

Comment: Please accept the Question Edit & Vote up my Answer!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are running [dropbox-sdk-python](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python) python package. 
This kind of error seems to be related to the version of dependencies like explained in this [thread](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/issues/114).

So please be sure that all dependencies have the correct version based on [requirements.txt](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/main/requirements.txt) file.

To check the version of all installed dependencies run the following command with the virtualenv activated.

```
pip freeze
```

Comment: I have checked the dependencies, they are updated to the latest version, i even uninstall and reinstalled them but yet the error occurs

Comment: they must be equal to the ones present in the requirements.txt file. are they equal?

Comment: `requests==2.25.1
six==1.15.0
stone==3.2.1`

Comment: please try to install requests==2.18.1